# CALayer borderColor Error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have very strange error here is my snippet of code:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGRect fr = rect;

fr.size.width = fr.size.width-2*rad;
fr.size.height = fr.size.height-1;
fr.origin.x = rad;

// draw round corners layer
bglayer = [CALayer layer];
bglayer.borderWidth = 1;
bglayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; // Here I receive Error: Expected identifier before '[' token
bglayer.backgroundColor = bgColor.CGColor;
bglayer.cornerRadius = rad;
bglayer.frame = fr;
bglayer.zPosition = -5; // important, otherwise delete button does not fire / is covered
[self.layer addSublayer:bglayer];
......
.....
}
```

in line where: `bglayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;` 
I receive this error:

> Expected identifier before '[' token

Can somebody help me please :)

Comment: Try to use [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]; or [bglayer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] ];

Comment: [bglayer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] ];  is ok :)
Thank you